# Gorilla Mux - not routing as expected

Tags: go, routes

Help would be appreciated, clearly i am missing something very simple.

I have created what should be a simple test rig to route calls to different methods to different handlers.

In stead the simple get handler is getting all get requests and delete and put are not recognised!

so both localhost:8080/users
and

localhost:8080/users?id=1

get. routed to the getUsers route. The answer to  this must be trivial but i cant see it and hence you help would be appreciated.

Below is a complete listing of the test rig

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type User struct {
    Id   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Users []User

var users = Users{
    User{
        Id:   "1",
        Name: "Tula",
    },
    User{
        Id:   "2",
        Name: "Monty",
    },
    User{
        "3",
        "Merry",
    },
    User{
        Id:   "4",
        Name: "Paddy",
    },
    User{
        Id:   "5",
        Name: "Hendrix",
    },
    User{
        Id:   "6",
        Name: "Purdy",
    },
    User{
        Id:   "7",
        Name: "turnip",
    },
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.Path("/users/{id:[0-9]+}").
        Queries("id", "{id:[0-9]*?}").
        Methods(http.MethodGet).
        HandlerFunc(getUser).
        Name("getUser")

    r.Path("/users").
        Methods(http.MethodGet).
        HandlerFunc(getUsers).
        Name("getUsers")

    r.Path("/users").
        Methods(http.MethodPost).
        HandlerFunc(CreateUser).
        Name("CreateUser")

    r.Path("/users/{id:[0-9]+}").
        Queries("id", "{id:[0-9]*?}").
        Methods(http.MethodPut).
        HandlerFunc(updateUser).
        Name("updateUser")

    r.Path("/users/{id:[0-9]+}").
        Queries("id", "{id:[0-9]*?}").
        Methods(http.MethodDelete).
        HandlerFunc(deleteUser).
        Name("deleteUser")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))
}

func getUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(users)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    } else {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "GetUsers!")
    }
}

func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "GetUser!")
}

func CreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "CreateUser!")

    var newUser User
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&newUser)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    } else {
        users = append(users, newUser)
        _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(users)
    }
}
func updateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "Update!")
}
func deleteUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "Delete!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch the url `localhost:8080/users?id=1`, the path is `/users`. The only path that maps to `GET /users` is:

```
    r.Path("/users").
        Methods(http.MethodGet).
        HandlerFunc(getUsers).
        Name("getUsers")
```

That's why the request maps to the `getUsers` method. The configuration for `getUser` doesn't actually make any sense. You have:

```
    r.Path("/users/{id:[0-9]+}").
        Queries("id", "{id:[0-9]*?}").
        Methods(http.MethodGet).
        HandlerFunc(getUser).
        Name("getUser")
```

Which would require a request like to something like `http://localhost:8080/users/1?id=1` (and then it ignores the id in the path). I would modify the configuration to look like this:

```
    r.Path("/users/{id:[0-9]+}").
        Methods(http.MethodGet).
        HandlerFunc(getUser).
        Name("getUser")
```

And then your requests would look like `http://localhost:8080/users/1`, `http://localhost:8080/users/2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple in the end only

```
r.Path("/users/{id:[0-9]+}").
            Queries("id", "{id:[0-9]*?}").
            Methods(http.MethodGet).
            HandlerFunc(getUser).
            Name("updateUser")
```

Became

```
r.Path("/users").
            Queries("id", "{id:[0-9]*?}").
            Methods(http.MethodGet).
            HandlerFunc(GetUser).
            Name("updateUser")
```